# Will NpgsqlConnection.Open throw an error if the port is closed?

Tags: npgsql

I wrote a test and at the time it seemed that if I had

```
NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(<valid string with port #>);
connection.Open();
...
```

with the corresponding network port closed, then connection.Open() would throw an exception. Now the code is

```
using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    ...
```

and I am getting feedback that this code may actually continue even if the port is closed. What is the behavior of NpgsqlConnection - is it guaranteed that connection.Open() will throw if the specified port is not opened?

I tried examining [NpgsqlConnection.cs](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/dev/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnection.cs/#L153) and [NpgsqlConnector.cs](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/dev/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnector.cs) but couldn't pin it down. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `NpgsqlConnection.Open()` will throw an exception if PostgreSQL isn't running on the potty specified ("connection refused").

Adding a `using` does nothing more than dispose the connection at the end of the block, after the exception has already been thrown.